# how to call java class from mysql procedure via the sys_exec?

Tags: mysql, exec

I want to execute the java code via he sys_exec in MySQL.
I configured the sys_exec via the **CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS STRING SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.dll';**
When I run command **SELECT sys_exec(" java HelloWorld ") FROM dual** , this is not worked.

but it is works in window command line.
**C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data>java HelloWorld**

hello

Also the system command is works fine as below.
 **SELECT sys_exec(concat("dir"," /s > C:\out.txt") ) FROM dual**  works fine in mysql.

If I want to execube **SELECT sys_exec( " java -cp .;mail.jar;mailapi-1.4.2.jar SendMailTest " ) FROM dual** in mysql procedure; how can I do, what I missed when using this command? could you give an example for reference?

**C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data>java -cp .;mail.jar;mailapi-1.4.2.jar SendMailTest**  is works in window command line too.

Comment: Were you able to do that?